# How do I create a search box in my website that works?

Tags: html

How would i create a search box in my website that when i search for something it takes me to google. here is my code: - it doesnt work when i click the search button.

```
<div class="searchBox" >

<form action="https://www.google.co.uk/" method="get" >
<input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search Here..." size="20" />
<input type="button" value="Search" />
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just redirecting the user, you don't need to use the form action. Just redirect the user with javascript on button click to the link you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="searchBox" >
  <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search Here..." size="20" />
  <button id="someButton">Search</button>
</div>
```

Now get the value of `input` and passes this as a query into google's url.

JS:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    var value = $( 'input' ).val();
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+value;
});
```

Comment: If you just said that he needs to rename the text input from "Search" to "q", and action from "google.com.uk" to "google.com", would be the same. But I got the idea.

Comment: That's good to know. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You need a submit button (`type="submit"`), not a regular button (which is just for hanging JavaScript from).

You need to set the `action` to the *correct* URL (which is `https://www.google.com/search`).

You need to give your text input the *correct* `name` (which is `q`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your action directed to the url google actually does the search at. That's `google.co.uk/search`.

Your input field's `name` will be the query param, and google expects this to be `q`. So your form should look like this:

```
 <div class="searchBox" >
  <form action="https://www.google.co.uk/search" method="get" >
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Here..." size="20" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the button type to `submit`, the name of the input field to `q`, and the target of the form to the correct base page `/search` so it actually fills all the right fields:

```
<form action="https://www.google.co.uk/search" method="get" >
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Here..." size="20">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Note that a sample here won't work as Google forbids frame access. Also I removed the `/>` endings from the `input` fields as that [is deprecated in HTML5 for 'empty' elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/1729885).

Answer (score 0):

If your specifically trying to use Google there is a handy generator Google developed to make this easy.

Try https://cse.google.com/cse/

Comment: i want to know how to do it technically.